# Bind class to an instance of another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an JS application where I'm using multiple timers (digital, analog). I would like to use a base class for the `Timer` with the functions: start, stop, update, etc.

Every time there is a timer created there are also new `onChange` event created. So when the timer ticks multiple instances get an update, not only the one where the timer is created in.

My question is: how can I bind and `Timer` instance the another class?

**Timer class:**

```
class Timer = {

    constructor() {
        this.seconds = 0;
    }

    start() {
        this.timer = setInterval(update, 25);
    }

    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    update() {

        this.seconds += 1;

        //emit data
        let event = new Event("timer-tick");
        event.detail = {
            seconds: seconds,
        }

        document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

DigitalTimer class:

```
class DigitalTimer = {

    constructor() {
        this.timer = new Timer();
        this.handleEvent();
    }

    handleEvent() {

        $('body').on('timer-tick', function(e) {
            //tick, do somehting with it.
        });
    }

    start() {
        this.timer.start();
    }

    stop() {
        this.timer.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think all you need to do is not to fire timer-tick events *globally* on the `document.body` - instead register the callbacks with the individual `Timer` instance and then call these from your `update` method instead of using dom events.

Comment: @Bergi Can you explain a little bit more; I don't understand how I then call the update function.

Comment: Keep an array of functions (or of complete `DigitalTimer` instaces) and call those `handleEvent` methods in the `update` method instead of firing a DOM event. Alternatitely, use `jQuery.Callbacks()` or some other event emitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get it working by binding an `on` and `trigger` event on a plain object.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#working-with-plain-objects

Working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/q5s6cud3/

```
class Timer {

  constructor() {

    let self = this;

    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
        self.update();
    }, 1000);   
  }

  update() {

     $(this).trigger('timer-tick');
    }
}

class DigitalTimer {

  constructor() {

    this.timer = new Timer();

    $(this.timer).on('timer-tick', function() {
        console.log('yes'); 
    });
  }
}

const digitalTImer = new DigitalTimer();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) method on the Function prototype that does what you want.

```
start() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 25);
}
```

On a side note, you shouldn't rely on `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to increment the time. Of course they are useful to make periodic calls, but the elapsed time isn't guaranteed. You can instead compare an initial [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) object with a new one on each call.